# Loopers - Handlers - Threads

Tags: java, android, android-looper

So, I am working with some code that performs seemingly asynchronous tasks and uses the typical callback/listener model to receive callbacks.

My problem is that sometimes the callbacks never fire if I hold up the thread that called the operation.

Considering the following snippet of code:

```
doAsync(new Callback(){

    // Callback here
});
```

The internals of `doAsync()` are using a handler and the `main looper`.

Considering I call this code from `Thread A` can somebody please outline the effects of blocking the `Thread A` right after this call.

Also, what are the effects of running the Handler on `main looper` and `local looper` will it determine the thread that the above callback is executed on? I ask this because if I block `Thread A` then the callback never executes.

Answer (score 0):

calling in Async Task does not block the main thread...doInBackground method executes the operations in background thread...if you want to update the UI after your execution in background has completed you must override the onPostExecute() method....there are some other hooks for UI thread too like onProgressUpdate and OnCancelled in AsyncTask....please check the java doc of AsyncTask for details

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input but my questions has nothing to do with Async task.